# How to calculate errors of best value of parameters that obtained from MCMC method and observational data

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, variance, mcmc

I had a model and some observational data. I used the MCMC method to obtain the best free parameters and used some coding to plot contours of 1 to 3 sigma confidence levels (as you see in the plot). I want the +/- value of sigma for each best value in any confidence level but I know that it is not symmetric. So, I didn't find the common equation of square variance useful. Is there any other way to calculate +/- errors?
[this is my contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOQLZ.png)

[this is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOwWJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `np. percentile(w, [15, 85])`, `np. percentile(w, [5, 95])` and `np. percentile(w, [0.5, 99.5])` in the final Gaussian probability and found errors for each confidence level correctly